# Trying to change source of image onHover with jquery

Tags: html, jquery

I am trying to change the image of an arrow to a darker version using jquery. I believe the code is right, it's just not executing on the page. The file does load.

HTML

```
            <article>
                <a href="about" id="learnLin"><h2 class="head4"> Learn more<span class="float-right"> <img id="image" src="right-arrow.png"> </span></h2> </a>
            </article>
```

Jquery

```
$( "#learnLin" ).mouseover(
      function() {
        $("#image").attr("src", "right-arrow-dark.png");
      })
```

Comment: Are your IDs correct? Is the new image src correct? Without seeing your HTML it's hard to tell. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71290075/edit) to include the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

Considering the path of image is correct

```
    <img id="image" src=""this.src='right-arrow.png'" 
onmouseover=""this.src='right-arrow-dark.png''" onmouseout="this.src='right-arrow.png'"/>
```